# How do I test the number of API calls the app makes in Cypress test

Tags: cypress

I'm using the Cypress intercept command to check certain API calls are made, and now I want to check that *only* those calls have been made.

There does not seem to be any provision in `cy.intercept` to catch excess calls.

How do I define an exact list of api calls and fail the test if actual list does not match expected list, for example

```js
const expectedCalls = [...]
cy.intercept(api).as('api')
cy.wait('@api').should('deep.eq', expectedCalls)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to wait for each expected call, then check the number of calls at the end

```js
const expectedCalls = [...]
cy.intercept('api-url').as('api')

cy.visit('/').then(() => {

  expectedCalls.forEach(call => {
    cy.wait('@api')
      .then(intercept => expect(intercept.request.url).to.eq(callUrl)
  })
  cy.wait(500)             
  cy.get('@api.all')     
    .should('have.length', 3)  
})
```

Answer (score 1):

To check for too many calls you can trap the error from the last intercept

```js
// wait for expected calls
expectedCalls.forEach(call => cy.wait('@api'))

// wait once more
Cypress.once('fail', (error) => {
  if (error.message.includes('No request ever occurred')) { 
    // this is ok, don't fail the test
    return
  }
  throw error
})
cy.wait('@fetch')                              // if this succeeds
  .then(() => throw 'Error: too many calls')  // then fail the test
```